# How to flag first occurrence of a vowel, move preceding consonants to end

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been instructed to create a PygLatin translator in Python - I'm very much a beginner. I have to translate any random input sentence. As of now, I need to be able to flag the first occurrence of a vowel in a word and transfer all the consonants preceding to the end of that word.

```
def encrypt():
    modify_split = list(sentence.split()) 
    letter = list(word)
    for letter in word:
        if letter == "A":
            print(word[1:] + "*" + word[0:1] + "AY")
        if letter == "E":
            print(word[1:] + "*" + word[0:1] + "AY")
        if letter == "I":
            print(word[1:] + "*" + word[0:1] + "AY")
        if letter == "O":
            print(word[1:] + "*" + word[0:1] + "AY")
        if letter == "U":
            print(word[1:] + "*" + word[0:1] + "AY")
```

It is currently printing every word per letter in the sentence, and not splitting at the vowel at all. Is there a simple way for it to loop through a list, find the vowel, and let me split the word there? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Sample input:

```
"Computer science is great"
```

Expected output:

```
"omputer*cay ience*scay is*~way eat*gray"
```

Comment: I'm a little confused, can you give an example of an input and an expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup your `vowels` in a string then using `enumerate` once you encounter a character that is in `vowels` you can store its `index` to `slice` your original string

```
s = 'this'
vowels = 'aeiou'

for i, v in enumerate(s):
    if v.lower() in vowels:
        x = i
        break

print(s[x:] + s[:x]) # => isth
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `word[1:]` with `word[length:]` and `word[0:1]` with `word[0:length]`

You want to use `length` because that is the current index of the loop. `word[length:]` will then give you all the letters in the word starting from the index of that vowel, and `word[0:length]` will give you the letters in the string up until that vowel.